# Scanning an array js object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

**Hello, I want to make a basic visual editor for my plugins.**

```
 let x = {
        tag : "a",
        atts : {
            href : "/",
            class : "a",
            text:"link"
        },
        components:[
            {
                tag : "b",
                atts : {
                    class : "a",
                    text:"asdsad"
                },
                components:[
                    //...
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

I have an js object like this. I want to get all "components" properties in this.

```
function render_blocks(blocks){
        for (let i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++) {
            const block = blocks[i];
            let $block_html = $("<"+ block.tag +">",{...block.atts});
            if(block.components){
                for (let k = 0; k < block.components.length; k++) {
                    const block_comp = block.components[k];
                    let $block_html_comp = $("<"+ block_comp.tag +">",{...block_comp.atts});
                    $block_html.html($block_html.html()+$block_html_comp[0].outerHTML);
                }
            }
            html = $block_html[0].outerHTML;
            console.log(html);
        }
    }
```

I am using a this function to convert js blocks to html. However this func is very bad :P.

Please HELLLP...

-Edit:
How can I scan nested components properties in my object? They may be a lot of. I am searching a efficient way.

Comment: I think you forgot to ask a question.

Comment: How can I scan nested components properties in my object? They may be a lot of. I am searching a efficient way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use recursion

```
let x = {
    tag: "a",
    atts: {
      href: "/",
      class: "a",
      text: "link"
    },
    components: [
      {
        tag: "b",
        atts: {
          class: "a",
          text: "asdsad"
        },
        components: [{ last: "last" }]
      }
    ]
  };

  let componentsArray = [];

  function getComponents(obj) {
    if (!obj.components) {
      return;
    }
    componentsArray.push(obj.components);
    obj.components.forEach(component => getComponents(component));
  }

  getComponents(x);
  console.log("componentsArray ", componentsArray);
```

Comment: Your answer better than my answer. :)  However, I think that making it as api (with oop) is better. So other people can use it easily.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem myself.
**Answer**

```
// sample blocks
let x = {
  tag: "a",
  atts: {
    href: "/",
    class: "a"
  },
  components: [{
    tag: "b",
    atts: {
      class: "a",
      text: "asdsad"
    },
    components: [{
      tag: "b",
      atts: {
        class: "a",
        text: "asdsad"
      },
      components: [
        //...
      ]
    }]
  }]
}

function Block(block) {
  this.components = []
  if (block.components) {
    this.components = block.components;
  }
  this.block = block;
}

Block.prototype.get_components = function() {
  return (this.components ? (this.components.length <= 0 ? false : this.components) : false);
}

Block.prototype.find_inner_components = function() {
  let has_components = this.get_components();
  let parent_components_arr = [];
  let section_components_arr = [];
  while (has_components) {
    let cur_components = has_components;
    has_components = false;
    for (let i = 0; i < cur_components.length; i++) {
      let new_block = new Block(cur_components[i]);
      section_components_arr.push(new_block);
      has_components = has_components || new_block.get_components();
    }
    parent_components_arr.push(section_components_arr);
    section_components_arr = [];
  }
  return parent_components_arr;

}

let a = new Block(x);
console.log(a.find_inner_components())
```